# Why won't .png files download with Python script while it works for other image types?

Tags: python, image, file, png

I am trying to search the source code of a webpage, and download various files from it using Python. This script searches the source code for .jpg files and downloads them all as expected. However, upon modifying the script (changing ".jpg" to ".png", as shown below), I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "img.py", line 19, in <module> urllib.urlretrieve(images[z], "image"+str(z)+".png")
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 91, in urlretrieve
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 237, in retrieve
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 461, in open_file
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 475, in open_local_file
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/images/adapt-icon-search.png?1342791397'
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re

print "enter url of site (such as 'dribbble.com')"

url = raw_input()
fullurl = "http://"+url

src = urllib2.urlopen(fullurl)
src = src.read()

images = re.findall('src="(.*\.png[^"]*)', src)

z=0
while z < len(images):
    urllib.urlretrieve(images[z], "image"+str(z)+".png")
    print "done"
    z+=1
```

Insight as to why this script doesn't work for .png files would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE: below is a sample of the source I am wanting to search through:

```
<span rel="tipsy" title="This shot has rebounds." class="rebound-mark has-rebounds">1</span>
                </a>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>
        <a href="/Dash" class="url" rel="contact" title="Dash"><img alt="Avatar-new" class="photo fn" src="http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/107759/avatars/original/avatar-new.png?1339961321" /> Dash</a>
        <a href="/account/pro" class="badge-link">
    <span class="badge badge-pro">Pro</span>
</a>
    </h2>
```

Comment: Can you post a longer traceback?

Comment: Sure! I just updated my question to include the traceback in its entirety.

Comment: Add a `?` to the things you exclude in your regex: `images = re.findall('src="(.*\.png[^"?]*)', src)`

Comment: I think your regex is finding more than just the filename - hence the error (ie. not being able to find '/images/adapt-icon-search.png?1342791397')

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I added the "?" as instructed, but it returned the same traceback.

Comment: Can you post a little of the html source you are parsing?

Comment: @ChipJust I just updated my question to include a sample of the code being searched (a part with a .png file)

Comment: Just remove the end bit; `images = re.findall('src="(.*\.png)', src)` - you don't need to match anything after the file extension right?

Comment: @mutzmatron Upon doing so I got the same traceback error on the line: `urllib.urlretrieve(images[z], "image"+str(z)+".png")` like before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the error you are getting is this:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/images/adapt-icon-search.png?1342791397'

What's happening is that the web page you're scraping has some PNG references that do not include the domain name included in the URL. When you try to fetch them in your `while` loop, it fails because you're only providing the location on the remote host: `/images/adapt-icon-search.png?1342791397`.

You need to extend your code to detect those kinds of URLs (which are perfectly legal, and in fact, very common). For the kind you're hitting here, you'll just need to prepend the matched URL with the host name of the server (e.g. `http://dribble.com/`).

You will probably also want to handle relative URLs, which also exclude the hostname, but start without a `/` character. Those will need to be prepended with the previous page's path, if there was one. So if you were scraping `http://dribble.com/foo/bar.html`, you'd need to prepend a relative URL with `http://dribble.com/foo/`.

There's likely a library that will automate handling of non-absolute URLs for you, perhaps as part of the web-scraping process. I'm afraid I don't know much about web scraping first hand, but perhaps somebody else can suggest one in a comment.

Comment: This is the right diagnosis.  `urlparse.urljoin` comes in handy here.